# Multiple click on JButton press

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

How to perform different action on each click with only one JButton..
please help me..
Here is my code..

```
btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        int clicks;
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");

            Object source = e.getSource();
            if(source == btn1){
                clicks++;
                if(clicks==1){
                    txt1.setText("a");
                    clicks=0;
                }
                if(clicks==2){
                    txt1.setText("b");
                    clicks=0;
                }
                if(clicks==3){
                    txt1.setText("c");
                    clicks=0;
                }
            }

        }

    });
```

please help me..

Comment: Don't reset the click count until it reaches 3. Buttons are not a good choice for detecting multiple mouseclicks, it's not what they were designed for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `MouseListener/Adapter` rather than an `ActionListener`, implement `mouseClicked`, and use `MouseEvent.getClickCount()`

Comment: MouseListeners on a button are a bad idea as buttons can be triggered by the keyboard and by the program, neither of which will trigger the MouseListener. Generally speaking, buttons are simply a bad choice for what the op seems to be trying to achieve

Comment: @MadProgrammer disagree with you here. If the OP really wanted what you are proposing, s/he would have selected the other solution. It seems that OP really did want to use click count as a series of rapid clicks to set the label.

Comment: It seems to me the OP doesn't know what they are doing...You could use a car as boat, but it wouldn't work as well as boat...

Answer (score 0):

You are resetting `click` with every action and thus only get action "a".

```
btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        int clicks;
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");

            Object source = e.getSource();
            if(source == btn1){
                if(clicks%3 == 0){
                    txt1.setText("a");
                }
                if(clicks%3 == 1){
                    txt1.setText("b");
                }
                if(clicks%3 ==2){
                    txt1.setText("c");
                }
                clicks++;
            }

        }

    });
```

Comment: And why should the op use this over some other solution?

Comment: @MadProgrammer because it gets to the other outputs or am I missing something?

Comment: Don't tell me, tell the op. Dumping a bunch of code on the,most always helpful